# raise TooManyRedirects( aiohttp.client_exceptions.TooManyRedirects: 0, message='', url=URL

Tags: python, asyncio, асинхронность

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import asyncio
import aiohttp



async def gather_data():
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsProactorEventLoopPolicy())
    headers = {"Accept": "*/*",
               "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36", }
    url = 'https://2gis.ru/ufa/search/%D0%92%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/firm/70000001006794970/55.992071%2C54.746479/tab/reviews'

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsProactorEventLoopPolicy())
        response = await session.get(url=url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), 'lxml')
        cards = soup.find(сlass_='_1i94jn5')
        print(cards)


async def main():
    await gather_data()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Ошибка:

```
C:\Users\79876\PycharmProjects\Jarvis\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/79876/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/main_2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\79876\PycharmProjects\Jarvis\main_2.py", line 29, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\79876\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\79876\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\79876\PycharmProjects\Jarvis\main_2.py", line 23, in main
    await gather_data()
  File "C:\Users\79876\PycharmProjects\Jarvis\main_2.py", line 16, in gather_data
    response = await session.get(url=url, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\79876\PycharmProjects\Jarvis\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 588, in _request
    raise TooManyRedirects(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.TooManyRedirects: 0, message='', url=URL('https://2gis.ru/ufa/search/%D0%92%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0,%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/firm/70000001006794970/55.992071,54.746479/tab/reviews')

Process finished with exit code 1
```